# DB2 Visual Studio Add-In with VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to get DB2 Visual Studio Add-In working for Visual Studio 2015.
But no matter what I try, every time I try to update the entity framework model for the Database I get the following error.

> Unable to convert runtime connection string to its design-time equivalent. The libraries requeird to enable Visual Studio to communicate with the database  for design purposes (DDEX provider) are not installed for provider 'IBM.Data.DB2'.

As per the following thread VS2015 should be supported since DB2 10.5 Fix Pack 6 from December 2015:
[Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 Support](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=3722e479-9aaf-4711-bdf0-de14c14ad210)

I tried installing the add-in from Fix Pack 6 linked in the thread and the current add-in from Fix-Pack 7, but both give me the same error message.

[image: Unable to convert runtime connection string to its desing-time equivalent.]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  If so, what was your solution?

Comment: @barrypicker: No, we still use VS 2013 for updating EF.